# Whats the difference between the 'Code Refactoring' and the 'Analyzer with Code Fix' template

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I thought I'd delve into writing a custom code analyzer, so that I can enforce a rule and and allow code fixes to be applied.
Upon opening VS after installing the required workload I see the following available templates:

[image]

- Code Refactoring
- Analyzer with Code Fix
- Standalone Code analysis Tool

What are the differences? How would i know what to pick?

Comment: The following tutorial is about 'Analyzer with Code Fix' : [Tutorial: Write your first analyzer and code fix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/tutorials/how-to-write-csharp-analyzer-code-fix)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The "Code Refactoring" template gives you a VSIX extension with a separate project for the refactorings. The extension shows a new entry in the "Quick Actions" menu when the cursor is on matching code. This way, you can provide a quick code fix without having to define an additional analyzer ID and showing the user an entry in the error list.
- The "Analyzer with Code Fix" template gives you a VSIX extension and a separate project for the analyzer which can also be deployed via NuGet. The analyzer can be used to show a squiggly line below matching code, showing an entry in the error list, which can be configured to be a message, warning or even an error - providing a code fix is *optional*.
- The "Standalone Code Analysis Tool" template gives you a console project, that will [open a solution workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/work-with-workspace). This way, you can analyze your projects without having to install any VSIX extensions or NuGet packages to the project or the IDE - it is supposed to be called from a command line, which makes most sense when used on a build server. The template does not include any analyzers or refactorings.